# Jokes {went/were going} over my head

Tags: past-tense, sentence-structure

If there is one joke that I don't understand I might say:

> The joke went over my head.

but what if I don't understand a series of jokes in the context of a movie, for example, someone suggested to me?
In this case should I say:

> Jokes **went** over my head one after another.

or:

> Jokes **were going** over my head one after another?

I am also wondering if there is a difference in connotation beteeen the two sentences.
(to me, for some reason, the second one seems to have a humorous connotation but I am not sure if that is the case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a movie I would likely say something like "That scene went over my head". I _might use your "one after another" construction if talking about some comedian's routine.

I don't like your second variant at all, it sounds far too passive, and also like the fault is somehow the joke's rather than with you as the listener.

Comment: Thank you. I can  clearly see the passivity in the sentence after reading your answer. I'm wondering, what if the jokes are actually bad for most people and that sentence was used intentionally with passivity for humorous effect with a very close friend, do you think in this case they might get offended or do you think it would be OK?

Comment: For something where listeners agree it isn't funny I would probably say it is flat: "Everyone agreed that routine simply fell flat."